# IDE for Python 2.7 and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ide

at the moment i am using the IDLE of python, but I am really missing the "basic" IDE features like Code Cempletion and Suggestion of used variables. IS there an IDE that supports these and works with OpenCV? 
I'm pretty new to both, so I am sorry if I lack knowledge.

Comment: PyCharm is a popular IDE for Python. I see no reason why it wouldn't work for OpenCV.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally every IDE for Python should work with OpenCV (it's just a wrapper for C++ lib, not something more complicated). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python?rq=1) you have a big list with comparision of features. Right now i'm using Sublime Text, because i'm working on quite small project and i don't need "big" IDE like Eclipse.
Important note about Sublime - if you often need to test something in console, consider installing [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin - it allows you to run Python (or almost any other language or shell) in Sublime tab, so you can use it with all editor features (e.g. code completition)